# MySQL Workbench failed to connect

Tags: mysql-workbench

I can't figure this one out. I can't connect to a server using MySQL Workbench, I tried any kind of connection methods. The error message I get is

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at AT 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
>
> Invalid for this platform protocol requested(MYSQL_PROTOCOL_SOCKET)

[image]

Comment: Did you verify if the server is running? Are you able to connect from the `mysql` command-line  client?

Comment: Have you installed for the first time, or is this a previously good system, and are now unable to connect. If its a new system, can you confirm MySQL is started?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ok, but I used xampp to open my server for localhost and it worked. Should I open it differently for this one? I know I'm a newbie :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very unusal error message which I haven't seen before, especially on Windows. It has probably to do with how the server is installed. As a newbie it would definitely be the best choice to use the [Windows Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) for all required parts. This will install the server properly too.

By using xampp you are on your own to check whether a server is installed and running as a service, as well as the proper configuration. For troubleshooting watch [my video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY) where I tried to explain most common pitfalls for beginners.

Note: you can open the connection without actually being connected. In that case MySQL Workbench allows to do all those things that don't require a valid server connection, e.g. log file viewing, config file editing, service start/stop etc. Use this to check your server's configuration. Make sure it accepts TCP/IP connections (there's also a short section in the video about this).

**Update:**

1. Downvoter, please add a comment why you think my answer is bad.
2. Re-reading the error message I got another idea: could it be that you used `local socket/named pipe` for the connection? If so try with normal TCP/IP.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem, in my case I originally created the connection with the "Local Socket/Pipe" option selected in the "Connection Method" drop down. Trying to switch back to "Standard (TCP/IP)" did not work and caused the error mentioned by OP. I had to delete the connection and start over by selection "Standard (TCP/IP)" from the start. The connection was successful after that.

Comment: What the heck do you know... same thing for me. Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem you must check the "Others" field in Advanced tab

If you had the connection stored with a socket option you will find a "socket=." (or anything similar)

Delete it

e.g. http://prntscr.com/k63pua